# Bash command-line completion function for vim and emacs 'scp://' remote file paths

Tags: bash, vim, emacs, autocomplete, bashrc

For easily specifying remote files for editing with `vim` or `emacs` from the shell, I would like to have tab-completion like available for `scp`.

Completions for `scp` work well and fast, if your
[`.ssh/config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) is
[correctly](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/)
[configured](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-faster-connections.html).

So why not for `vim`, and other `ssh`-capable editors? I feel, the standard `bash-completion` package could benefit from a completion function set for ssh-capable editors, which AFAIK does not yet exist publicly.

(In environments, where `afuse` and `sshfs` are available to me, I use "as work-around" [a user-level `afuse` `sshfs` auto-mounter daemon spawned from shell init](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294965/127903) to on-demand background mount remote file-systems into a tree under `~/scp/`.)

Answer (score 1):

I played around with your solution.
Here is a slightly tweaked version which works better for me
on a Mac OSX 10.11 system using homebrew.

First, in a file rvim_fun.sh, I define

```
vi () {
  local params=();
  while [[ ! -z $1 ]]; do
    # test if arg begins a sequence S of characters
    #    - . A-Z a-z 0-9 @ _
    # followed by a colon,
    # if so, we replace S: by scp://S/ to match vim syntax

    if [[ "$1" =~ ^[-.A-Za-z0-9@_]*:.*$ ]]; then
      params=("scp://${1/://}" "${params[@]}");
    else
      params+=("$1");
    fi;
    shift;
  done;
  echo vi ${params[@]};
  $HOME/bin/vi ${params[@]};
}
```

I found that this somehow works better for me (also, I have a program vi 
installed in ~/bin that invokes MaxVim).

Now, on my Mac, I installed bash-completion via homebrew.
All I had to do was place the following in my 
.bashrc file:

```
case "$-" in
*i*)    source rvim_func.sh 
        complete -F _scp -o nospace vi
        ;;
*)  ;;
esac
```

So I didn't directly source anything else, except for what one has
to do with homebrew:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

That is from the homebrew discussion board...

Anyway, this works pretty well for me now...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hacked up something that "misuses" the available standard `_scp` bash completion function to enable completion of remote hosts/paths/files.

A vim-wrapping function then mangles the returned paths in the form `ho.st:/fol/der/fi.le` into the vim-expected form `scp://ho.st///fol/der/fi.le`.

```
vim () {
  local params=();
  while [[ ! -z $1 ]]; do
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^[a-z0-9-]*:/.*$ ]]; then
      params=("scp://${1/:\//\/\//}" "${params[@]}");
    else
      params+=("$1");
    fi;
    shift;
  done;
  echo vim ${params[@]};
  /usr/bin/vim ${params[@]};
}
. /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/scp
complete -F _scp -o nospace vim
```

For emacs use: `params=("/scp:$1" "${params[@]}");`

But, this setup could work better. Currently, this approach has the following minor shortcomings:

- I can't tab-complete vim `-o ptions`. But I rarely use them anyway.
- The `scp` options are still in there (but I never *see* them)
- Only works for scp:// paths. But I only rarely use others like rsync or http.
- The last 2 lines feel *sub-optimal*, and leave my env cluttered with lots of helper functions.

  I tried using this as second-last line instead, but this does not seem reliable:

  `_completion_loader scp`

  Sometimes, but not in tmux, spawning a new shell resulted in '_completion_loader not found'-Error. Yet running `_completion_loader _scp` results in functioning completion without error for this shell.

This works well enough for me, since I can just type the rare `-o ption` or `http://` path.

But I do not consider this a *good* solution/answer, and won't accept it, because I am hoping for a better one to come up.

Note: I previously tried just using a [modified standard supplied _known_hosts_real() function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294309/127903), found a way to [run-time patch it to support more options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294473/127903), but then couldn't quickly wrap that into `_vim()`, so I just ignored the minor inconveniences of using `_scp()`, and started using that.