# How to specify protocol prefix containing ":" to bash-completion function _known_hosts_real

Tags: bash, autocomplete, hostname

I am attempting to use bash-completion for URLs of the form "proto://host". Without the ":", I see expected behavior, with the ":" present, the URL comes out "faulty".

Bash completion has a function for hostnames, `_known_hosts_real`.
It has a parameter `-p PREFIX` that I want to use.

How to reproduce "wrong" behavior:

You need at least one "known" host on your system:

E.g. `echo "gdns.google 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/hosts`

*Run these commands for functioning example:*

```
$ unset COMPREPLY 
$ _known_hosts_real -p 'http//' -- "gdn"
$ echo $COMPREPLY 
http//gdns.google
```

*Non-working example:*

```
$ unset COMPREPLY 
$ _known_hosts_real -p 'http://' -- "gdn"
$ echo $COMPREPLY 
//gdns.google
```

Note the only difference is the added colon in "http://". The problem here is the prefix has lost the protocol specifier and the colon. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Michael_Veers pointed out, that this is expected behavior (+1), so I should write my own function.

But instead I wrote a patch for the standard `_known_hosts_real` into my bashrc, that enables additional options:

- `-t` Do not trim to left colon
- `-S <suffix>` Add custom suffix

In `.bashrc`:

```
 . <(type _known_hosts_real | sed -e '
 1d;s/acF:p:/actS:F:p:/;
 s/^.*c)/\nS)\nsuffix=$OPTARG\n;;\nt)\nnotrim=1\n;;\nc)/;
 s/\(__lt\)/[ $notrim ]||\1/')
```

Now this works as expected:

```
$ unset COMPREPLY
$ _known_hosts_real -p "scp://" -S '/' -t -a gdn
$ echo $COMPREPLY
scp://gdns.google/
```

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behaviour, as `_known_hosts_real` calls `__ltrim_colon_completions`, which removes prefixes terminated by colons. `_known_hosts_real` is intended for use with the `ssh` known hosts file, so you should probably define your own function on the basis of `compgen -A hostname`.

Comment: thanks for tracing that. In fact, I *want* the known ssh hosts to be included. So instead of writing something entirely new with basically the same function, I decided to add a patch to _known_hosts_real to my `.bashrc`, which adds options "-S" (suffix), and "-t" (dont trim).